# CloudFormation YAML State Machine: INVALID_JSON_DESCRIPTION for unrecognized token

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions, serverless-application-model

I have the following code to deploy a Step Functions State Machine using CloudFormation:

```
...
DefinitionString: 
        !Sub
          - |
            {
              "StartAt": "Save Artifact to S3",
              "States": {
                "Save Artifact to S3": {
                  "Type": "Task",
                  "Resource": ${lambdaArn},
                  "Next": "Format Notification"
                },
                "Format Notification": {
                  "Type": "Task",
                  "Resource": ${lambda2Arn},
                  "Next": "Publish to SNS"
                },
                "Publish to SNS": {
                  "Type": "Task",
                  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
                  "Parameters": {
                    "TopicArn": ${snsArn},
                    "Message.$": "$.message",
                    "Subject.$": "$.subject"
                  },
                  "End": true
                }
              }
            }
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt SavetoS3Function.Arn
            lambda2Arn: !GetAtt NotifyUserFunction.Arn
            snsArn: !Ref NotifyUserTopic
...
```

Using SAM to deploy on AWS, I get the following error:

```
Invalid State Machine Definition: 'INVALID_JSON_DESCRIPTION: Unrecognized token 'arn': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')  at [Source: (String)...
```

Everything else looks correct, so what is going on here? All the Arns are being referred correctly inside the Definition String, so that's probably not the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be a json, so `lambdaArn`, `lambda2Arn` and `snsArn` should be in **quotations**:

```
        {
          "StartAt": "Save Artifact to S3",
          "States": {
            "Save Artifact to S3": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "${lambdaArn}",
              "Next": "Format Notification"
            },
            "Format Notification": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "${lambda2Arn}",
              "Next": "Publish to SNS"
            },
            "Publish to SNS": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
              "Parameters": {
                "TopicArn": "${snsArn}",
                "Message.$": "$.message",
                "Subject.$": "$.subject"
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
```